# Melhorar a qualidade de um screenshot feito com ffmpeg

Tags: vídeo

Existe um modo de melhorar a qualidade de uma 'foto' tirada a partir de uma webcam usando o FFmpeg?

Estou usando o código abaixo e ele resulta em duas 'fotos' de muito baixa qualidade.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Integrated Webcam" -qscale:v 5 -t 1 -strftime 1 -segment_format jpeg foto%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.jpeg
```

Alguma dica sobre como melhorar a qualidade?